# How to remove a keyword from a given sentence

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentence-similarity

How can I remove a **keyword** from a phrase?

For example,

> Lionel Andrés Messi is an Argentine professional footballer who plays as a forward and captains both Spanish club Barcelona and the Argentina national team.

How can I remove a keyword (except for the name of the person) from this sentence, such as "American", "footballer", "Barcelona" to name a few.

I have realised that the keyword must be a **noun**, and I came across a library called NLTK, and maybe that can help me what I want to achieve.

Function example:

```
remove(sentence, word_to_not_remove)
```

```py
>>> sentence = 'Lionel Andrés Messi is an Argentine professional footballer who plays as a forward and captains both Spanish club Barcelona and the Argentina national team.'
>>> remove(sentence, 'Lionel Andrés Messi')
footballer
```

Comment: Can you explain with more details what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is NER(Named Entity Recognition).

As a starting step, you can Look at Spacy [ https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent ]

```
import spacy
text = "Lionel Andrés Messi is an Argentine professional footballer who plays as a forward and captains both Spanish club Barcelona and the Argentina national team."
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(text)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

```
Andrés Messi 7 19 PERSON
Argentine 26 35 NORP
Spanish 101 108 NORP
Barcelona 114 123 GPE
Argentina 132 141 GPE
```

PS: If you need a specific Entity Extraction, you may have to train it for your specific use case

More docs: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities

Visualise here: https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent

Comment: Do you reckon I can randomly select from a specific entity and remove it?

Comment: I don't have an understanding of your specific use case, but yes you can @Sonav